# how to calculate weighted average of percentages

Tags: average, percentages

I have a question that may be basic but I do not seem to find the solution for this and so would appreciate any advice please. If we have the following (example taken from https://www.robertoreif.com/blog/2018/1/7/why-you-should-be-careful-when-averaging-percentages):

```
                 DO NOT LIKE CHOCOLATE      LIKE CHOCOLATE          TOTALS
Children         10,000                     90,000                  100,000  
Adults           160,000                    240,000                 400,000
Totals           170,000                    330,000                 500,000
```

and we want to calculate the percentage of people who like chocolate across the entire population, we do:

330,000/500,000=66% and NOT (90,000/100,000=90%) + (240,000/400,000=60%) / 2 which would give us 75%.

However, I am struggling to apply the same thinking to the weighted average of percentages. In my case, I have something like:

```
ORGANISATION   TOTAL_INDIVIDUALS*   REGION    REGION_OF_TOTAL_INDIVIDUALS      NUMBER_PREMISES_IN_EACH_REGION_WITH_DECENT_INTERNET  TOTAL_PREMISES_IN_EACH REGION
A              15,000               1         10,000                           50                                                   100  
A              15,000               2         3,000                            40                                                   212
A              15,000               3         2,000                            90                                                   109
B              5,000                4         4,500                            66                                                   90
B              5,000                5         500                              33                                                   123
```

*TOTAL_INDIVIDUALS that are part of the organisation

I cannot link the individual to their premise, I only have access to a proxy - the number of premises in the region where the individual lives that have decent internet. I would like to calculate the percentage of individuals/premises with decent internet for each organisation taking into account the number of individuals per region (that's my weight). Any advice please?

**More details below please:**
I cannot link each individual to their premise. What I have is the quality of the internet connection per region and I know in which region each individual lives so I am assuming the individuals from a specific region have the quality of the internet connection of the region. I would like an overall metric of quality of internet connection for each organisation. E.g. organisation B has 5000 individuals, 4500 come from region 4 with good quality of internet connection (66/90=73%) and 500 from a region 5 with lower quality of internet connection (33/123=27%), but I cannot just do 66+33/90+123 because the number of individuals coming from each region for that organisation is not 2500 & 2500, but 4500 & 500, as in, there are more people coming from region 4 than 5, so I need some sort of weighted average here.

**Proposed solution:**

```
ORGANISATION   TOTAL_INDIVIDUALS   REGION    REGION_OF_TOTAL_INDIVIDUALS      NUMBER_PEOPLE_WITH_DECENT_INTERNET   PERCENT_PEOPLE_WITH_DECENT_INTERNET_PER_ORGANISATION
A              15,000              1         10,000                           (50/100)*10,000=5,000                (5,000+566+1,651)/15,000=48%
A              15,000              2         3,000                            (40/212)*3,000=566                   (5,000+566+1,651)/15,000=48%
A              15,000              3         2,000                            (90/109)*2,000=1,651                 (5,000+566+1,651)/15,000=48%
B              5,000               4         4,500                            (66/90)*4,500=3,300                  (3,300+134)/5,000=67%                                     
B              5,000               5         500                              (33/123)*500=134                     (3,300+134)/5,000=67%
```

Comment: What does "total individuals per region" mean?

Comment: Thanks saulspatz and apologies. I've edited my question- I've included 'region' in the table. "total individuals per region" refers to the number of individuals part of the organisation that come from a specific region. E.g. for organisation A, which has a total of 15,000 individuals, 10,000 come from region 1.

Comment: Does it make sense?

Comment: I assume that "individuals/premises" means "individuals and premises", right?   For premises, I don't see a problem.  For individuals, you could assume that the average number of individuals per premise is independent of the quality of the internet connection,  but that's a little dicey.  In the first region we have $100$ people per premise, so it might well be that larger premises have better internet.  In that case, you don't have enough data, or if you do, you haven't shared it with us.

Comment: I did not explain myself very well to start with - I've edited my question with more details now. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Yes, it means exactly what I supposed it means, but my comments still hold.  We can compute the number you want if all premises in a region are the same size (most unlikely) or we can compute an approximation by assuming that the size of the premise is independent of the quality of the internet connection.  I have no idea if this is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: When you say "In the first region we have 100 people per premise". This is not what that variable means. It means there are 100 premises in region 1. Additionally, we know that out of those 100 premises, 50 have a decent internet connection, and so we can construct a metric of quality of internet connection for that region (50/100). The size of the premises can be disregarded here.

Comment: Yes, and there are $10,000$ people in the region, giving $100$ people per premise.

Comment: No, sorry, 10,000 people part of the organisation come from region 1, but region 1 is made of a different number of people. 100 premises is a representation of the region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am assuming the individuals from a specific region have the quality of the internet connection of the region.

A region does not have a quality of internet connection according to your figures. Some premises in each region have good quality, and some have poor quality.

I suppose what you are trying to say is that the ratio of premises with good connectivity to total premises is a useful predictor of the ratio of people with good connectivity to total people in the same region.
For example, in Region $1$ we find that $50\%$ of premises have good connectivity,
therefore we estimate that $50\%$ of people in Region $1$ have good connectivity.

This is only a way of estimating (that is, guessing) how many people have good connectivity. If $9000$ people in Region $1$ are all in one premises and the others are distributed over the other $99$ premises, clearly you either have more than
$90\%$ or less than $10\%$ of people having good connectivity in Region $1,$
depending on the connectivity at the one premises where the $9000$ people are.
Since you have no data about how many people are at the various individual premises, you have no way to know if such an effect is occurring or not.

But if you accept the method of estimating number of people with good connectivity,
you can simply make those calculations for each region and add a column to your table containing those figures.
(That is, add a column for "number of persons with good connectivity".)
And then you will be able to add up numbers of persons with good connectivity
just like you added up numbers of persons who like chocolate.

Comment: Thanks David. I can understand the issue you raise. Regarding the last paragraph, I think I cannot just do that because e.g. organisation B has 5000 individuals, 4500 come from region 4 with good quality of internet connection (66/90=73%) and 500 from a region 5 with lower quality of internet connection (33/123=27%), but I cannot just do 66+33/90+123 because the number of individuals coming from each region for that organisation is not 2500 & 2500, but 4500 & 500, as in, there are more people coming from region 4 than 5, so I need some sort of weighted average for the org. Does it make sense?

Comment: That's why you need to insert the extra column that has **number of people** with good connection. Then for good measure, delete the "premises" columns and try to forget that you ever saw them so that you will not be misled. Pretend that all along you had only data about number of people in each region and number of people with good connections. The numbers $66$ and $33$ should not appear anywhere in your calculations after that point.

Comment: Thanks David. I have added that column that you mentioned in my question, but I still don't understand what I should now do with it to get an overall metric of quality of internet connection for each organisation? Just to be clear, I do not have access to the total number of people per region. What I have is the region of the total number of people part of the organisation. I have rename that variable in my main table above.

Comment: Is it not true that there are $15000$ individuals in organization $A$ and that $10000$ of then are in Region $1$? I think we are only concerned with people who are in the organization **and** live in the region. When I talk about "number of people" I mean only the people who were already listed in the fourth column. Pretend the only humans alive are the employees of the two organizations. They are the people we are talking about whenever we talk about people in this table.

Comment: The number of people in Region $1$ who have a good connection is most certainly **not** $50/100$. That is only half a person! The number of people should be a whole number. Since you have $10000$ people in Region $1$, and you have $50$ out of $100$ premises there with good connections, half of all those people should have good connections. What's half of $10000$? That's the number that should be in the last column.

Comment: Thanks David. I think I got it. I have modified the column and added a new one for the %. Would you agree with that?

Comment: That is what I had in mind. Within the limitations of the available data, I think you now have found the best answer you can get.

Comment: Many thanks David for your input on this.